# Subscript out of range, moving data from range to array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I am completely new to programming here.

I am getting a subscript out of range error on the following code:

```
b(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("trades").Range("AA & arxi +i-1:AD& arxi+i-1").Value
```

I believe it has to do with the syntax, or maybe because I haven't redimed `b(vdomada,4)` ?

In any case the data from the range do not go into the array. The result would be to input the data in the array and then export them in a different excel file(the exporting bit is not into the code provided)

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub report()
Dim b As Variant, arxi As Integer, telos As Variant
Dim LastDayRow As Integer, vdomada As Integer, i As Integer, z As Integer
Dim LastDay As Date


Application.Workbooks("Back Office 2019.xlsx").Activate

Sheets("trades").Select
LastDayRow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
telos = Cells(LastDayRow, 12)
arxi = InputBox("Please enter the row for the start of the week")
vdomada = LastDayRow - arxi
ReDim b(vdomada) As Variant
For i = 1 To vdomada

b(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("trades").Range("AA & arxi +i-1:AD& arxi+i-1").Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the line to this `b(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UST trades").Range("AA" & arxi + i - 1 & ":AD" & arxi + i - 1).Value
`

Comment: Try to avoid activate and select.

Answer (score 2):

Few things that might help. I would remove the following-

```
ReDim b(vdomada) As Variant
For i = 1 To vdomada

b(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("trades").Range("AA & arxi +i-1:AD& arxi+i-1").Value
Next i
```

And replace it with-

```
b = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("trades").Range("AA" & arxi & ":AD" & vdomada).Value
```

See if that helps.

I think your error originates from giving Range something it doesn't know what to do with and from trying to assign a 2D range to an array that's been defined as 1D. I don't think you need to ReDim the array in this case.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UST trades")
    b(i) = .Range(.Cells(arxi + i - 1, "AA"), .Cells(arxi + i - 1, "AD")).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid `.Activate`

```
With Workbooks("Back Office 2019.xlsx").Sheets("trades")
    LastDayRow = .Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    telos = .Cells(LastDayRow, 12)
    arxi = InputBox("Please enter the row for the start of the week")
    vdomada = LastDayRow - arxi
End With
```

Additionally, variables which takes whole numbers( NOT decimals) is better to declare `As Long`. `Longs` can take higher bigger numbers.